# Replace properties of specific elements in object

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

here is the data:

```
const data = {
  element6: {
    col: 2,
    row: 3,
    text: "Col2, Row1"
  },
  element1: {
    col: 1,
    row: 1,
    text: "Col1, Row1"
  },
  element8: {
    col: 3,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col2, Row1"
  },
  element2: {
    col: 1,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col1, Row2"
  },
  element5: {
    col: 2,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col2, Row2"
  },
  element3: {
    col: 1,
    row: 3,
    text: "Col1, Row3"
  },
  element4: {
    col: 2,
    row: 1,
    text: "Col2, Row1"
  },
   element7: {
    col: 3,
    row: 1,
    text: "Col2, Row1"
  },
   element9: {
    col: 3,
    row: 3,
    text: "Col2, Row1"
  },

};
```

What I want to do is to add a property `ind` (which equals to element's `col` value) and overwrite `col` (to the smallest value of selected) to all elements which are in the same `row` and different `col`.
For example, `elements` 2, 5 and 8 are in `row: 2`, so they would change to:

```
{
  element8: {
    col: 1,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col2, Row1",
    ind: 3
  },
   element2: {
    col: 1,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col1, Row2",
    ind: 1
  },
    element5: {
    col: 1,
    row: 2,
    text: "Col2, Row2",
    ind: 2
  },
}
```

Note, I don't want to change the order of object in `data`.
Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

Use the for...in statement iterates, as @Ravenous mentioned

```
const smallColl = currentRow => {
  let small;

  for (let key in data) {
    const { col, row } = data[key];

    if (row !== currentRow) continue;

    if (!small || col < small) small = col;
  }

  return small;
};

// another method
const smallColl = currentRow =>
  Math.min(
    ...Object.values(data)
      .filter(({ row }) => row === currentRow)
      .map(({ col }) => col)
  );

for (let key in data) {
  const { col, row } = data[key];
  data[key].ind = col;
  data[key].col = smallColl(row);
}
```

for better performance, use memoization:

```
for (let key in data) {
  const colMin = {};

  const { col, row } = data[key];
  data[key].ind = col;

  const min = colMin[row] || smallColl(row);

  data[key].col = min;

  if (colMin[row]) colMin[row] = min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with a help of `lodash` (or any other helper library)
Assuming your `data` is object (by the way, the order of keys in object is not guaranteed!)

```
    const res = _.chain(data)
        .toPairs()
        .groupBy(([key, val]) => val.row)
        .mapValues(list => {
            const smallestCol = _.minBy(list, ([key, val]) => val.col)[1].col
            return list.map(([key, val]) => [key, {...val, ind: val.col, col: smallestCol}])
        })
        .values()
        .flatten()
        .fromPairs()
        .value();
```

It may be worth noting that as of ES2019 almost all of those functions (except for `groupBy` and `minBy`) are available in JS standart library, though they do not chain so well

```
    function groupBy(array, selector) {
        return array.reduce((res,curr) => {
            const key = selector(curr)
            if({}.hasOwnProperty.call(res, key)) {
                res[key].push(curr)
            } else {
                res[key] = [curr]
            }
            return res
        }, {})
    }
    function minBy(array, selector) {
        return Math.min(...array.map(selector))
    }
    const groupedbyRow = groupBy(Object.entries(data), ([key, element]) => element.row)
    const remappedValues = Object.values(groupedbyRow).flatMap(list => {
        const smallestCol = minBy(list, ([key, val]) => val.col)
        return list.map(([key, val]) => [key, {...val, ind: val.col, col: smallestCol}])
    })
    const res = Object.fromEntries(remappedValues)
```